# CSS Checkbox Labels alignment

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So Im working with wordpress and CF7 for the contact form, and I'm trying to use css to realign my labels but the last line still refuses to go down, I've been playing with the margins and width but it just gets stuck there, and I'm not sure how to push it down.
Here's the css I have so far

```
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap{
width: 650px;
display: block;
vertical-align: middle;
position: relative;
padding-left: 35px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
```

}

and this is my result [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Hbt.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you also provide some html with your question. It's likely that you need each of your checkbox elements to have `display: block;`

Comment: Provide more context, what does your html code for the styling above look like? Perhaps use https://jsfiddle.net/ to show the actual html and css you're having